# Wiring partial view to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm in a bit of a rut with MVC3 partial views.  What I'm trying to do is have a partial view within one of my pages, and have that data from the partial view stored in the model that gets passed back into the main view.  Though, what's happening right now is that after submitting the data, the model returned back to the controller has the partial view model set as null.

**Model**

```
public class MyModel {
    ...(other variables)...

    [Required]
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual MyPartialView myPartial { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcPartialViewExample.Models.MyModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>

    ...(other data)...

    @{ 
        Html.RenderPartial("_MyPartialView", Model.MyPartialView, new ViewDataDictionary());
    }
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
      @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyModelController : Controller
{
    private MyModelContext db = new MyModelContext();

    //
    // GET: /PartialViewTesting/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new MyModel());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the *Model.MyPartialView* object back to the controller, then you need to add another Action method to the controller.  Should look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyPartialView model)
{
    // handle postback here
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thanks for the help there. I was just bit confused on this line:  `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_MyPartialView", Model.MyPartialView, new ViewDataDictionary()); }` I was assuming that the data would be sent to Model.MyPartialView, but looking further into the problem, that wouldn't make any sense, thanks for the help